# Celery task function custom attributes

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a celery task function that looks like this-

```
@task(base=MyBaseTask)
@my_custom_decorator 
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    my_task.ltc.some_func() #fails - attribute ltc doesn't exist on the object
```

and my_custom_decorator looks like this

```
def my_custom_decorator (f):
    from functools import wraps
    ltc = SomeClass()
    @wraps(f)
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        ret_obj = None
        try:
            f.task_cache = ltc
            ret_obj = f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            raise
        return ret_obj
    _inner.ltc = ltc
    return _inner
```

I see that this is because the actual callable object that is invoked to execute the task is an object of type celery task class.
How can I retain my attribute 'ltc' on this object so it can be accessed from within the task as show above i.e - `my_task.ltc.some_func()` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think one easy way to do that would be to introduce `ltc` as a keyword parameter..

```
@task(base=MyBaseTask)
@my_custom_decorator 
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    ltc = kwargs['ltc']
    ltc.some_func()
```

maybe this way:

```
def my_custom_decorator (f):
    from functools import wraps
    ltc = SomeClass()
    @wraps(f)
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        ret_obj = None
        try:
            f.task_cache = ltc
            kwargs['ltc'] = ltc
            ret_obj = f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            raise
        return ret_obj
    _inner.ltc = ltc
    return _inner
```

I don't know if there's a celery's task way to do this. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that decorated function should take ltc as an argument?

Comment: It's. And have no problems. I'm sorry I didn't check what exactly were you doing. The problem is that when my_task code is executed, the name my_task points to other function which is the returned by `@task`, and that function doesn't have a ltc attribute. You should check if `@task` exposes the internal function via some attribute..