# Attributes of Celery Tasks

Tags: python, celery

Does celery purge/fail to copy instance variables when a task is handled by delay?

```
class MyContext(object):
    a = 1


class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self):
        print self.context.a

from tasks import MyTask, MyContext
c = MyContext()
t = MyTask()
t.context = c
print t.context.a
#Shows 1
t.delay()

=====Worker Output
Task tasks.MyTask[d30e1c37-d094-4809-9f72-89ff37b81a85] 
raised exception: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'",)
```

It looks like this has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068283/celery-task-function-custom-attributes), but I do not see an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work because the instance that actually runs isn't the same instance where you call the delay method. Every worker instantiates it's own singleton for each task.

In short, celery isn't designed for the task objects to carry data. Data should be passed to the task through the delay or apply_async methods. If the context object is simple and can be pickled just pass it to delay. If it's complex, a better approach may be to pass a database id so that the task can retrieve it in the worker.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation

Also, note that in celery 2.5 delay and apply_async were class methods.